# scrapy program return no output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy

I'm new to Python and trying to use scrapy to build a web scraper. I followed the tutorial from the following URL:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html
Just like the tutorial, after running the program in Visual Studio Code Text Editor, I checked my current files directory but couldn't find any HTML files.

Did do something wrong or did install it wrong?

Here are the codes below

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name ="quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls =[
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'quotes-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you typed the code yourself instead of copying the code from the tutorial. You're ignoring the comma after the url, which is causing problems with your code.

##### solution:

Put the following part of the code in

```py
        urls = [
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/'
        ]
```

Replace with:

```py
        urls = [
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/'
        ]
```

***Note: comma separated after url is required.***

[image]